# How do you read the IN keyword inside a conditional operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Stumbled upon this block of code:

`var text = 'text' in this.props ? this.props.text : '';`

but even though I understand the context, I have difficulties reading this particular line. It is described as defensive code, because in React it can be replaced with `getDefaultProps()` method

Comment: What specifically about this line is confusing? It appears to be a pretty basic use of [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and [the ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is seeing if there is a prop called `text`. If so, the ternary says `var text = this.props.text;`. If there is no `text` in `this.props`, the ternary says `var text = '';`. It's defensive code because it makes `text` a string instead of `undefined` if it isn't included in the props.

Answer (score 0):

The [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator checks if a property is a member of an object.

```
('text' in this.props) ≈≈ (Object.keys(this.props).includes('text'))
```

---

So what the snippet is doing is checking to see if `text` is defined in `this.props` and if so, returning it, else returning an empty `String`.

Comment: As a nitpick, those expressions are not equal. `in` finds object members from the prototype chain too, where as `getOwnPropertyNames` finds only the own properties of an object.

Comment: Good distinction, I was trying to find an alternate way but didn't want to show a test for `!== undefined` since `undefined` is a valid value and would also not be the same as `in`

Comment: I'll change it to that then

Comment: Please [don't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), I was wrong ... it also finds own properties only.

Comment: >The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

Comment: NIce operator, "not so strictly equal" = ).